# Camera does not work

Tags: android, camera

I tried to access the camera from the phone, it worked 3 times, after the screen went black (Print below) in API 24, I tested it on a cell phone with API 22 and it worked, with the API 24 no, does anyone know how to solve it?

```
public class fotos extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    private ImageView ivPhoto;
    private Button btTakeaaPhoto;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fotos);

        ivPhoto = findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto);
        btTakeaaPhoto = findViewById(R.id.btTakeaPhoto);;

        btTakeaaPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //config.showProgress(true, progressBar, context);
                dispatchTakePictureIntent();
            }
        });
    }

    private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            ivPhoto.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The screen stays like this for a few seconds and then the camera closes and returns to the activity.

Edit: The application does not stop working, it just opens the camera screen, turns black, and after a few seconds it closes, as I already said

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

The problem is not the permissions, they have already been given, I already looked at the configurations to confirm. That's not the problem.

Comment: Have you checked if you request the camera permission from current device ?

Comment: Have you added camera & storage permission also post your logcat if you are getting some error & exception

Comment: @Chauyan Yes, the permissions are ok, it worked 3 times, after that it stayed like this, with black screen

Comment: @AkshayKatariya No, there was no exception, just open, black and then the camera closes and returns to normal activity

Comment: Have you added runtime permissions and handle them properly

Comment: @AkshayKatariya I'll add the manifesto to get better.

Comment: @AkshayKatariya Look now

Comment: just add my sample, you can see the reference repo, it's simply forked from google

Comment: @WotonSampaio have you tried on any other phone. does this occur on all phones are is this device specific?

Comment: @Raghunandan 
I tried on one with android 5.1, it worked, on my it's 7.0 not

Comment: @WotonSampaio this could be device specific can you test it on other device with the same os version?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I did it work, and do you know how? I rebooted the cell phone, do you know how I discovered it? I tried using the camera's function of WhastApp and showed me the message that it was not possible to access the camera at that moment, which was for me to reboot, so after that, it magically worked. WWWTTFFFF

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check several parts in your project. 

1. in you AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

check if you've already add such permission requests.

2. in your source code, for permission request from Android 6. You should have following code.

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        requestCameraPermission();
        return;
}
```

for requestCameraPermission() function

```
if (shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        new ConfirmationDialog().show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
    } else {
        requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION);
}
```

you should ask that user to grant the permission and implement the callback function

```
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                       @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA_PERMISSION) {
        if (grantResults.length != 1 || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.request_permission))
                    .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        }
    } else {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

After you granted the permission, open your camera and config the correct parameters. you can check the repo here https://github.com/wangchauyan/camera_sample.git, which I used to create my own camera application. 
Hope that would be helpful.

Comment: Man, the problem is not the permissions, they have already been given, I already looked at the configurations to confirm. That's not the problem.

Comment: I'm going to open the git project to test

Comment: It did not stop working, it just opened, it had the black background, and than closed, without exception, but I noticed the logcat error: `04-17 01: 33: 37.754 27274-27274 / com.example.android.camera2basic E / Camera2BasicFragment: Could not find any suitable preview size`

Comment: seems that preview size error. which device are you going to test?

Comment: I tested it on ZenFone 3 max

Comment: gg, didn't have that device. will ask my friends if they have one. I did test that on Nexus 6. worked well.

Comment: @WotonSampaio i think you get log error shoud be because of the resolution issue. you can change the setting here - MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH/ MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT, it default uses 1080p to open camera, it sometimes causes problem if the camera can not use 1080p, you can chage these two parameters said, 720p (1280, 720)

Comment: I'll try with the emulator, just a moment

Comment: In the emulator worked, both your example and my app;

Comment: Life does not make sense anymore

Comment: LOL, dude, you should try another device for that. ZenFone 3 might not be a good sample

Comment: I do not have another one here with the same API, the other one I have is a 22, and as I said, it worked

Comment: Where do I add this: MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH?

Comment: in fragment, you can find that parameters

Comment: Dude, I did it work, and do you know how? I rebooted the '-' cell phone, do you know how I discovered it? I tried using the camera's function of WhastApp and showed me the message that it was not possible to access the camera at that moment, which was for me to reboot, so after that, it magically worked '-' WWWTTFFFF

Comment: ....... dude, life is tough, thank you for saving others' time to debug this. Good luck :), that's a camera hardware issue. LOL @WotonSampaio